# C cannot get search number in array inside while loop to work and "double free or corruption" error

Tags: c, for-loop, random, while-loop, corruption

i'm noob in C programming and I'm sorry for this question which could be very easy, but i cannot solve this problem after searching all the afternoon.
I'm trying to write a program that generates a random number, checking that this is not already present in a list contained in the file number.txt. At the end the program has to ask if you want to extract another number and, if Yes, re-run it.
I tried various for and while loops but none of these worked: numbers in the list are often extracted, What's wrong?

Moreover, sometimes, after various iterations, the program stops with the error
"double free or corruption (! prev)", what causes it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define rangeMAX 27 //Upper limit of range.
#define rangeMIN 1  //Lower limit of range.


int main()
{
  int get, i, n;
  int num[5];
  char r;
  FILE *filer;
    filer = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");
    printf("When you are ready press any key to continue\n");
    getchar();
    if (filer == NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR Creating File!");
        exit(1);
    }
    do {
        num[5] = 0;
        n = 0;
        i = 0;
        free(filer);
        get = 0;
        r = 0;
            srand(time(0)); // this will ensure that every time, program will generate different set of numbers. If you remove this, same set of numbers will generated every time you run the program.
            get = ((rand() % (rangeMAX-rangeMIN+1)) + rangeMIN); // generate random number.
        for (n = 0; n < 5; n++){
        fscanf(filer, "%d\n", &num[n]);
        }
            for (n = 0; n < 5; n++){
                if (get == num[n]){
                printf("false\n");
                printf("%d\n", n);
                break;
                }
            }
                i=get;
                printf("%d\n",i);
    printf ("Do you want another number? Y/N ");
    scanf (" %c", &r);
    } while (r == 'y' || r == 'Y');
    return(0);

}
```

Comment: can you post the input `numbers.txt` as well?

Comment: Why `free(filer);`?

Comment: `num[5]` is accessing outside the bounds of the array (which is indexed from 0 to 4)

Comment: Thanks phil M, the count starts at 0!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several problems in your code

1) `printf("ERROR Creating File!");` is a bad message, you do not try to create the file, you open it to read inside

2) `num[5] = 0;` has an undefined behavior because you write out of *num* whose size is 5 (`int num[5];`)

3) `free(filer);` *filer* is a `FILE *`, the behavior is undefined, what did you wanted to do ? This is very probably the reason of your :

> Moreover, sometimes, after various iterations, the program stops with the error "double free or corruption (! prev)", what causes it?

4) `get = 0;` is useless, you do not use *get* before to assign it again with the result of *rand()*

5) `r = 0;` is useless too because you do not use *r* before to do `scanf (" %c", &r);`

6) `srand(time(0));` that must be done only one time at the beginning of the program, not several times because if you do two times in the same second the `rand()` will return the same value.

7) you do

```
    for (n = 0; n < 5; n++){
    fscanf(filer, "%d\n", &num[n]);
    }
```

for each `do .. while` but you never go back to the beginning of the file, so each time you progress and you do not check the end of the file. When you reach the end of the file `fscanf(filer, "%d\n", &num[n]);` does nothing and *num* is unchanged.

You just need to read the numbers from the file only one time at the beginning of the execution

8) You ask *rand()* to return a value between 1 and 27, so only few possibilities, this is probably why you have :

> numbers in the list are often extracted.

---

Here a proposal taking into account the remarks (except the last about the range of values), *numbers.txt* is not limited to 5 numbers.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#define rangeMAX 27 //Upper limit of range.
#define rangeMIN 1  //Lower limit of range.

int main()
{
  srand(time(0)); // this will ensure that every time, program will generate different set of numbers. If you remove this, same set of numbers will generated every time you run the program.

  FILE * filer = fopen("numbers.txt", "r");

  if (filer == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR cannot read numbers.txt");
    exit(1);
  }

  int * nums = NULL;
  int num;
  size_t sz = 0, nnums = 0;

  while (fscanf(filer, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    if (nnums == sz) {
      sz += 100;
      nums = realloc(nums, sz * sizeof(int));
    }
    nums[nnums++] = num;
  }
  fclose(filer);

  printf("When you are ready press any key to continue\n");
  getchar();

  char yn[16];

  do {
    int get = ((rand() % (rangeMAX-rangeMIN+1)) + rangeMIN); // generate random number.
    size_t i = 0;

    for (;;) {
      if (i == nnums) {
        printf("%d is not in the file\n", get);
        break;
      }
      if (get == nums[i]) {
        printf("%d is the number rank %d in the file\n", get, i + 1);
        break;
      }
      i += 1;
    }

    printf ("Do you want another number? Y/N ");
    if (scanf ("%15s", yn) != 1)
      break;
  } while (*yn == 'y' || *yn == 'Y');

  return(0);
}
```

Compilation and execution :

```
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ gcc -pedantic -Wall -g r.c
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ cat numbers.txt 
1 3 7 9 10 20 23
pi@raspberrypi:/tmp $ ./a.out
When you are ready press any key to continue

12 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
12 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
4 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
3 is the number rank 2 in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
12 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
15 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
16 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N Y
8 is not in the file
Do you want another number? Y/N N
```

Comment: Woooow! Your code makes more things than I can think! Thanks a lot! I'll study it and if there is something unclear I'll ask again!

Comment: @caesar753 sure you can

Comment: 1) i cannot understand what your first while loop does
2)what the meaning of `for (;;)`?
3)in your for loop i cannot figure out how the i variable gets the numbers contained in the file and read in the while loop (i guess) and so how the program knows  which line contains the extracted number, if present in number.txt

Comment: @caesar753  the _while_ at the beginning reads all the integers from the file, while 
_scanf_ read an integer it returns 1 (because the format manage only %d, so 1 element). To be compatible with any number of numbers in the file I do not use an array with a fixed size but realloc to increase its size, loot on internet about _realloc_

Comment: @caesar753 `for(;;)` is like `for(;true;)` or `while(1)`, it loops without condition, it is necessary to do a _break_ to go out (or a return of course)

Comment: @caesar753 _i_ is just an index in the array, `nums[i]` is one of the read numbers. The program doesn't know the line where a number was, only the rank of the number. As you see in my files all the numbers are on the same line, but using several lines changes nothing in the code nor at the execution, _fscanf_ bypass the newlines

Comment: @caesar753 if needed execute the program in a debugger step by step if you still do not understand and look at what happens / variables changes

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i studied your code and i understood more or less what your program does and how variables are assigned, but this is my problem now:
i set the dimension of the array to five because i want to read only the last (or the first, for now) five number in number.txt (which should be the latest extracted, because in a further step i'd like to append each extracted number in that file), so i managed to modify your code to do so (just modified the first while loop), and this works fine.
What i cannot solve is why your for(;;) loop works great and my code nope, that is why in my code

```
for (n = 0; n < sizeof(num[5]); n++){
        if (get == num[n]){
        printf("false\n");
        printf("%d\n", n);
        break;
        }
else{
        printf("true");
        break
    }
}
```

(added else) works only for the first number in the array, but if is extracted a number which is the second, the third ... in the array (which are loaded in the array, because i can print it) the program doesn't see it.

@stensal In my numbers.txt file each number is located in a new line.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my program grew and now has many new functions:

1. you can choose a file from which a list of names is loaded
2. you can choose the file containing the numbers that have been yet extracted in previous sessions
3. you can add the numbers of the students who weren't present at last lesson or who have a justistification for not having studied the lesson (I need this program to call students in classe)
4. If a number has been yet extracted the program tries a second and then a third extraction

and this is the code (comments are in italian)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#define rangeMAX 27 //Upper limit of range.
#define rangeMIN 1  //Lower limit of range.

int main()
{
  srand(time(0)); // this will ensure that every time, program will generate different set of numbers. If you remove this, same set of numbers will generated every time you run the program.

 char elenco[20], filelenco[30];
    printf("inserire il nome del file elenco: ");
    fgets(elenco, 20, stdin);
    elenco[strlen(elenco)-1]='\0';
    sprintf(filelenco, "%s.txt", elenco);

//lettura dell'elenco dei nomi
char nomi[27][20];
FILE * nomif = fopen(filelenco, "r");

  if (nomif == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR impossibile leggere %s",filelenco);
    exit(1);
  }

    size_t g = 0;

        for (g = 0; g <=27; g++) {
                fscanf(nomif, "%s", nomi[g]);
                }


//prompt per la scelta del file in cui leggere i numeri di quelli già chiamati
    char fname[20], filename[30];
    printf("inserire il nome del file: ");
    fgets(fname, 20, stdin);
    fname[strlen(fname)-1]='\0';
    sprintf(filename, "%s.txt", fname);
   FILE * filer = fopen(filename, "r");

  if (filer == NULL)
  {
    printf("ERROR impossibile leggere %s\n", fname);
    exit(1);
  }

//creazione dell'array contenente i numeri di quelli già chiamati
  int * nums = NULL;
  int num;
  size_t sz = 0, nnums = 0;
  char yn[16];
  int c;

  while (fscanf(filer, "%d", &num) == 1) {
    if (nnums == sz) {
      sz += 100;
      nums = realloc(nums, sz * sizeof(int));
    }
    nums[nnums++] = num;
  }
  fclose(filer);

//creazione del file contenente gli assenti della volta precedente e i giustificati
char data[30], nome[20];
char ass[20];
struct tm ora;
time_t now;
now = time(NULL);//epoch time
ora = *(localtime(&now)); //conversione nell'ora locale
strftime(data,30,"%Y%m%d",&ora); //formattazione della data secondo lo standard  YYYYMMDD
sprintf(nome, "%s_giustificati_%s.txt", data, fname); //creazione della stringa da usare come nome file
//printf("%s\n", nome);

FILE * assenti;

    assenti = fopen(nome,  "w+"); //creazione vera e propria del file, con il nome formato al comando precedente
    printf("Inserite i numeri degli assenti/giustificati\n");
    scanf("%[^\n]", ass);
    fprintf(assenti, "0 %s", ass);
    fclose(assenti);

//creazione dell'array degi assenit/giustificati tramite lettura del file appena creato
  assenti = fopen(nome, "r");
  int * nums1 = NULL;
  int num1;
  size_t sz1 = 0, nnums1 = 0;
  int d;

  while (fscanf(assenti, "%d", &num1) == 1) {
    if (nnums1 == sz1) {
      sz1 += 100;
      nums1 = realloc(nums1, sz1 * sizeof(int));
    }
    nums1[nnums1++] = num1;
  }
  fclose(assenti);

//attesa dell'input
  while ((getchar()) != '\n'); 

  printf("Se siete pronti premete un tasto per continuare\n");
  getchar();

//scelta della più grande tra le due variabili nnums (numero di elementi dell'array dei già chiamati) e nnums1 (numero di elementi dell'array degli assenti/giustificati) - serve per le iterazioni del ciclo for all'interno del do...while
    size_t max = ((nnums >= nnums1) ? nnums : nnums1);
//    printf("max %d\n", max);

//somma delle due variabili nnums (numero di elementi dell'array dei già chiamati) e nnums1 (numero di elementi dell'array degli assenti/giustificati)
//  size_t total = nnums + nnums1;
//  printf("total %d\n", total);

  do {
    int get = ((rand() % (rangeMAX-rangeMIN+1)) + rangeMIN); // generate random number.
    size_t i = 0;

//ciclo for che verifica che il numero non sia presente nel file dei già chiamati e in quello degli assenti e giustificati. Solo dietro queste due condizioni estrae il numero
    for (;;) {

    if (i == max) {
        printf("E' stato estratto il %d,\n ovvero\n", get);
    sleep(2);
    printf("%s\n", nomi[get-1]);
    filer = fopen(filename, "a");
    fprintf (filer, "%d\n", get);
    fclose(filer);
        break;
      }

//se il numero è gia presente nell'array dei già chiamati crea un interrupt e fa ripartire il do
      if (get == nums[i]) {
//      printf("%d is the number rank %d in the file\n", get, i + 1);
    printf("prima estrazione: Il %d e' gia' stato chiamato\n", get);
    get = ((rand() % (rangeMAX-rangeMIN+1)) + rangeMIN);
    size_t z = 0;
    for (;;) {
        if (z == max) {
            printf("E' stato estratto il %d,\n ovvero\n", get);
                sleep(2);
                printf("%s\n", nomi[get-1]);
                filer = fopen(filename, "a");
                fprintf (filer, "%d\n", get);
                fclose(filer);
                break;}

        if (get == nums[z]){
            printf("seconda estrazione: Il %d e' gia' stato chiamato\n", get);
                get = ((rand() % (rangeMAX-rangeMIN+1)) + rangeMIN);
                    size_t w = 0;
                    for (;;) {
                            if (w == max) {
                                    printf("E' stato estratto il %d,\n ovvero\n", get);
                                    sleep(2);
                                    printf("%s\n", nomi[get-1]);
                                    filer = fopen(filename, "a");
                                    fprintf (filer, "%d\n", get);
                                    fclose(filer);
                                    break;}

                            if (get == nums[w]){
                        printf("e' stato di nuovo estratto il %d\n", get);
                        break;}

                    w += 1;}
            break;}

        z += 1;}

        break;
    }

//se il numero è presente nell'array degli assenti/giustificati crea un messaggio a video e fa ripartire il do
    if (get == nums1[i]) {
    printf("Il %d, ovvero %s, era assente o e' giustificato\n", get, nomi[get-1]);
    break;
      }

      i += 1;
    }

//scelta se continuare ad estrarre o meno
    printf ("Volete estrarre un altro numero? Y/N ");
    if (scanf ("%15s", yn) != 1)
      break;
  } while (*yn == 'y' || *yn == 'Y');


  return(0);
}
```